# Example code for using Facebook Connect with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, facebook

Is there any good example code in Coldfusion 8 that shows how to use Facebook Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might take a look at [Facebook Developer Wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:ColdFusion) which has a link to [8 Minute Apps](http://cffacebook.wordpress.com/8-minute-apps/). Haven't tried any of this, but it would be a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the available [RIAForge](http://www.riaforge.org/index.cfm?event=page.search) (used search link because there are 5 of them already there) options? Havent used them personally, but descriptions give some hope.